# Why XAML's Margin attribute has four components not two?

Tags: wpf, xaml

When you see Margin attribute in a XAML file of WPF, it has four components. Why is this? The first two components make sense they are offset from top left window, but what is it for the third and fourth components when we have Width and Height?

```
<Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,27,0,0" Name="clickButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86" Click="clickButton_Click" />
        <TextBox Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,90,0,0" Name="textBoxOut" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Margin always has four components: left, top, right and bottom. Two components are just shorthand when top=bottom and left=right. And one component is shorthand when all four components are the same.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is good explanation of Margins and Paddings.

Answer (score 14):

The margin can be different on all sides of an element. Therefore the four elements are:

```
Margin="left,top,right,bottom"
```

refer here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx

Comment: @hitech, Your link is to localhost.

Comment: Updated link. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

When specifying a margin in XAML you can specify 1, 2 or 4 parameters.

If you specify 1 (e.g. `Margin="10"`) then this value is applied to all sides.

```
margin="all_margins"
```

If you specify 2 (e.g. `Margin="10, 20"`) then the first value is applied to the left and right while the second value is applied to the top and bottom.

```
margin="horizontal_margins, vertical_margins"
```

If you specify 4 (e.g. `Margin="10,20,30,40"`) then the first value is applied to the left side, the second value is applied to the top, the third to the right and then fourth to the bottom.

```
margin="left, top, right, bottom"
```